# NextJS: react-firebase-hooks orderBy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, next.js

I am using this package https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks and the code below works.

```
const [posts, loading, error] = useCollection(
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .where('uid', '==', uid),

    {
      snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
    }
  )
```

However, when I add the orderBy to it, I got an error:
`Error: {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}`

```
  const [posts, loading, error] = useCollection(
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .where('uid', '==', uid)
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'),
    {
      snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
    }
  )
```

I wonder how should the query be constructed when using React-Firebase-Hooks.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I may be wrong but can you orderby by a different field if there's equality filter on another field? As per my understanding was, it wasn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add composite index:

```
collection post: uid Ascending createdAt Descending
```

Not sure how you get this error, but maybe you are able to get more details from it. I replicated it directly in node. And if you run such query directly in node you will get error massage with more details like:

```
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/<project-id>/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ck1wcm9qZWN0cy9zdXJ5amFrLXRlc3QtMDAvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzL3Bvc3RzL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgcKA3VpZBABGggKBHNvcnQQAhoMCghfX25hbWVfXxAC
```

If you hit the link in the error the index will be build automatically. The documentation to composite indexes is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview)

Comment: I did not see a link in the console, not too sure why.  I think there are errors in the query.

Comment: Query is correct, I have replicated it on my side. You can add composite index without the link just go to firebase console, open firestore and there is tab Indexes with button "Add index"

Comment: I just created the composite index, still seeing the same error, I must have done something wrong

Comment: Have you waited long enough creating an index can take a while...

Comment: phew, got it! works now! It has to be exactly as uid Ascending createdAt Descending